# DefineConstant in NuGet package's props based on the target platform

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

I'm building a multi-target NuGet package and I want it to provide a compile constant for the consumer:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>Xamarin.Mac20;netstandard2.0;uap10.0.17763</TargetFrameworks>
```

I want a certain feature to be only available for two of this targets. To do so I'm defining a custom constant:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('uap10.0.17763')) Or $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('Xamarin.Mac'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);FEATURE_AVAILABLE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now I want not only to use this constant in my current assembly I want to create a package from, but also in the consumer project. To achieve that I created a `Common.props` file and included it into the package:

```xml
<Import Project="Common.props" />
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="Common.props" Pack="true" PackagePath="build" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After building I can confirm my `Common.props` was added to the package and I could successfully consume it in the main project.

The main project targets the same 3 platforms as the package project. Now I just want to use `FEATURE_AVAILABLE` imported from the package so I can utilise only the available code from the package.

**The problem** is it doesn't respect the platform conditions that wrap the `DefineConstants` instruction in my main project like if it was executed before MSBuild knows the target framework it's going to build for. If I remove the condition, the constant is available in my main project code. With the condition in place it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out Nuget doesn't respect `Xamarin.Mac20` as a target name though dotnet itself does. When the packages are being restored, Nuget generates its own `PROJECT_NAME.csproj.nuget.g.props` file that includes the following line (cleaned up and sanitised):

```xml
<ImportGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'xamarinmac20'">
  <Import Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)MY_NUGET_NAME/VERSION/build/FILE.props" />
</ImportGroup>
```

Changing the target framework from `Xamarin.Mac20` to `xamarinmac20` solves the issue. I don't really want to do it for all of my dependent projects so I'll either be including the full import line manually or will find a way to configure Nuget to my needs.